# What is an analytical expression for so called value function $V^{\pi}$ in reinforcement learning?

Tags: probability, expected-value, markov-process, reinforcement-learning

One thing that struck me as odd when going through literature on reinforcement learning is how "theoretical" everything is. I expected the results in this field to be things that you can immediately punch into Python or MATLAB and get your hands dirty, but I am seeing most things in reinforcement learning is not expressed are an analytical fashion (and poorly defined - but maybe I am early on in the book).

For instance, this so called value function
[image]

[https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node34.html](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/%7Esutton/book/ebook/node34.html)

But what is $E_\pi$? I cannot punch $E_\pi$ into MATLAB, it is not a function that I am familiar with, so I must get rid of it immediately to arrive at an analytical expression that I can evaluate.

If $\pi(s,a)$ is a probability distribution as I suspect it is, then using the expression of an expectation for a discrete random value, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value,  $V^\pi(s)$ should be expressed as:

$$V^\pi(s) = \sum\limits_{a = 1}^n \pi(s,a)\left(\sum\limits_{k =0}^\infty \gamma^k r_{t+k+1}\right)$$

Can someone check if I have the expression for the value function at state $s$ correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the Sutton page you link to, emphasis mine:

> Recall that a policy, $\pi$, is a mapping from each state, $s$, and action, $a$, to the probability of taking action $a$ when in state $s$. Informally, the *value* of a state $s$ under a policy $\pi$, denoted $V^{\pi}(s)$, is the **expected return when starting in $s$ and following $\pi$ thereafter**.

Expressing the expectation isn't that simple, because subsequent rewards depend on subsequent transitions from state to state. This is why Sutton writes, "A fundamental property of value functions used throughout reinforcement learning and dynamic programming is that they satisfy particular recursive relationships."

Check equation [3.10](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node34.html#eq:Bellman-Vpi) on that same page for an expression that expresses this relationship.